# Change Background Image of RelativeLayout from within Java Class (Android App)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

So I am working on an Android application using Android 4.0 Library.

One of the activities of this application is made up of a RelativeLayout that has an image background and a toggle button.
The background image of the layout must change when the user toggles the button.

So it must be changed from inside the activity.java class:

```
if (toggleButton.isChecked()){

// Change the background of the activity to image 2 (for example)           
 }

else{ // when toggle button is off

// Change it back to image 1

}
```

Please help me with this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the method, `setBackground` in the  `View` class:

```
if (toggleButton.isChecked()){

// Change the background of the activity to image 2 (for example) 
View myView =  this.findViewById(yourViewId); 
myView.setBackgroundResource(yourImage);         
 }

else{ // when toggle button is off

// Change it back to image 1
// Change the background of the activity to image 2 (for example) 
 View myView =  this.findViewById(yourViewId); 
myView.setBackgroundResource(yourOtherImage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was kind of helpful. However, it didn't work like that. Somehow, the activity refuses to use the setBackground() Method.

Comment: I used the following:
Integer[] images = {
       R.drawable.image0,
       R.drawable.image1
     };

And then:
if (toggle.isChecked()){
          
         myView.setBackgroundResource(images[0]);     
            
        }
        
        else{
         myView.setBackgroundResource(images[1]); 
         
        }

This worked out for me :)