# Changing background image month wise

Tags: android, background-image

I want to change the background image as per the date displayed in text box in android studio. For Example, If the Date is 01-Jan,the background image will come as per January. If date is 2-Feb,then background image will come as per Feb. That is, every month has different background image.

Comment: Edit your question and provide us with your current code progress...

Comment: Please describe your current solution and where do you have problems in detail. Please read also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Let me know whether the answer helped

Comment: John Doe, I want to know that the code which you gave here. In which file I have to paste this, in XML or JAva. confused about this.

Comment: @NakulSharma is your java class

Answer (score 1):

> Every month has different background image

Use the code below to get the month. After that do whatever you want based on the month.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int thisMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    String name = getMonth(thisMonth);
    if(name.equals("Jan"))
    {
         View myView =  this.findViewById(yourViewId); 
         myView.setBackgroundResource(yourImage);    
    }
    else if(name.equals("February"))
    {
         ....
    }

    ......

    public static  String getMonth(int month){
    String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    return monthNames[month];
    }
```

Source : [Change Background Image of RelativeLayout from within Java Class (Android App)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17798774/5156075)